# IF cells = specific text, display assigned number as result in another cell

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm looking for some help on a simple formula that I cannot get right.

```
if    A6= bluethen cell A7 to display 1
or    A6= green then cell A7 to display 2
or    A6= red then cell A7 to display 3
```

anyone able to simplify this code or even in conditional formatting?

Comment: @pnuts Alright nice showing off with your fancy solution!

Comment: @pnuts thanks so much for your help bud. it works a treat. cheers everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one thing wrong with your programming lingo.

```
if    A6= blue     then cell A7 to display 1
or    A6= green    then cell A7 to display 2
or    A6= red      then cell A7 to display 3
```

Is incorrect, or rather, if you looked up the definition of [`OR`](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/or_vba.php) logical operator in VBA (or any other programming language), it would not match up with what you're trying to achieve.
What Im hinting at is, what you're doing here is not an `OR` operation, but rather a `ElseIf`, alternatively a [`switch / Case`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php) .

This would be how computer would interpret your code (if it could speak):

```
If A6 is blue, or green, or red
then display in cell A7 => ERROR CONFUSION (should I apply 1, 2 or 3?)
```

**Or is a logical operation, that can only be either evaluated as true or false. It cannot evaluate any further states (eg. 1, 2 or 3)**

For example

`IF(OR(A6="green", A6="blue", A6="red"), "If at least one is true", "Otherwise do this")`

**What you are trying to descirbe here instead could (should) be written like**

```
if        A6= blue    then cell A7 to display 1
else if   A6= green   then cell A7 to display 2
else if   A6= red     then cell A7 to display 3
else                  A7= "Haven't found a single correct condition"
```

Which would be equivalent to an answer:
*(The answers above are equivalent this, but abbreviated, technically omitting ElseIf, given formulas are not capable of ElseIf and need to be nested)*

`=IF(A6 = "blue", 1, If(A6 = "green", 2, If(A6 = "red", 3,"Haven't found a single correct condition"))`

Hopefully you understand now. It is very important to get basics like this correct at the very beginning while you can, otherwise it's going to cause a lot of confusion down the line!

Answer (score 1):

```
=If(A6 = "blue", 1, If(A6 = "green", 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(A6="blue",1,IF(A6="green",2,IF(A6="red",3,0)))
```

This to give all the given condition returns a value.

Note that once the cell doesn't contain any of the conditions it will display 0.